# Compactness of a parametrized set in an infinite dimensional space.

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces, compactness

I have a question regarding the compactness of a certain parametrized set in a infinite dimensional Hilbert space.

1. **Setup:**

Let $\mathcal{H}$ be a real seperable Hilbert space with scalar product $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ and induced norm $\lVert \cdot \rVert$. Further, let $\mathcal{Q} \subset \mathbb{R}^m$ be an arbitrary compact set.

Consider a mapping
$$
x: (0, \overline{\varepsilon}] \times \mathcal{Q} \to \mathcal{H}, \quad (\varepsilon, q) \mapsto x(\varepsilon, q),
$$
with the following properties:

1. $x$ is continuous on $(0, \overline{\varepsilon}] \times \mathcal{Q}$.
2. $x(\varepsilon,q)$ is unifomrly bounded, i.e., $\exists M \ge 0$ s.t. $\lVert x(\varepsilon, q) \rVert < M $ for all $(\varepsilon, q) \in (0, \overline{\varepsilon}] \times \mathcal{Q}$.
3. For all $q \in \mathcal{Q}$ the limit $\lim_{\varepsilon \to 0} x(\varepsilon, q) =: x^*(q) \in \mathcal{H}$ exists.

In this context I have the following questions.

2. **Question:**

a) I would like to know if the set
$$
X := \left\lbrace x(\varepsilon, q) : (\varepsilon, q) \in (0, \overline{\varepsilon}] \times \mathcal{Q}\right\rbrace
$$
is relatively compact, i.e., if the closure of the set $X$ is compact in $\mathcal{H}$.

b) A weaker (sequential) version of the upper statement would also be enough. I would like to know if the following statement is true:

For every sequence $\left\lbrace \varepsilon_k \right\rbrace_{k \ge 0} \subset (0, \overline{\varepsilon}]$ and every sequence $\left\lbrace q^k \right\rbrace_{k \ge 0} \subset \mathcal{Q}$ the sequence $\left\lbrace x(\varepsilon_{k}, q^{k}) \right\rbrace_{k \ge 0}$ has a cluster point, i.e., there exists a (strictly monotonically increasing) sequence $\left\lbrace k_l \right\rbrace_{l \ge 0} \subset \mathbb{N}$ such that $\lim_{l \to + \infty} x(\varepsilon_{k_l}, q^{k_l}) = x^{\infty} \in \mathcal{H}$ exists.

I am thankful for any answer, counter example, hint to the literature, or just your general gut feeling on this.

My feeling says the statement holds and I want it to hold but so far I have not been able to show it.

Kind regards

AverageJoe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set is not necessarily relatively compact, as the following example shows:

Take $\mathcal{H} = l^2(\mathbb{R})$ and $\{e_n\}_{n \geq 1}$ be the standard basis. For each $\epsilon \in (0, 1]$, let $e(\epsilon) \in \mathcal{H}$ be defined by,

$$e(\epsilon) = \cos(\frac{\pi}{2} \cdot \frac{\frac{1}{n} - \epsilon}{\frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n+1}}) e_n + \sin(\frac{\pi}{2} \cdot \frac{\frac{1}{n} - \epsilon}{\frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n+1}}) e_{n+1}$$

when $\frac{1}{n+1} < \epsilon \leq \frac{1}{n}$. That is, $e(\epsilon)$ rotates from $e_n$ to $e_{n+1}$ as $\epsilon$ decreases from $\frac{1}{n}$ to $\frac{1}{n+1}$.

Now, let $\mathcal{Q} = [0, 1]$. Define, for $\epsilon \in (0, 1]$, $q \in [0, 1]$,

$$x(\epsilon, q) = \begin{cases}
e(\epsilon)&, \text{ if }\epsilon > q\\
\frac{\epsilon}{q}e(\epsilon)&, \text{ if }\epsilon \leq q
\end{cases}$$

Then $x$ is continuous on $(0, 1] \times [0, 1]$, $\|x(\epsilon, q)\| \leq 1$ for all $\epsilon$ and $q$, and for any fixed $q$, $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} x(\epsilon, q) = 0$. However, $X = \text{range}(x)$ is not relatively compact, since $e_n = x(\frac{1}{n}, \frac{1}{2n}) \in X$ for all $n \geq 1$. This also shows that the sequential version you want is also false, though that is really the same thing as sequential compactness and compactness are equivalent in a metric space.

---

As requested, the following is a counterexample showing that an additional assumption that $\langle x^\ast(q) - x(\epsilon, q), x(\epsilon, q)\rangle \geq 0$ for all $\epsilon$ and $q$ is not enough to guarantee relative compactness either.

Again, let $\mathcal{H} = l^2$. This time we number the standard basis starting at 0, i.e., the standard basis shall be given by $\{e_n\}_{n \geq 0}$. We define $e(\epsilon)$ as before,

$$e(\epsilon) = \cos(\frac{\pi}{2} \cdot \frac{\frac{1}{n} - \epsilon}{\frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n+1}}) e_n + \sin(\frac{\pi}{2} \cdot \frac{\frac{1}{n} - \epsilon}{\frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n+1}}) e_{n+1}$$

when $\frac{1}{n+1} < \epsilon \leq \frac{1}{n}$, $n \geq 1$. We observe that because we start numbering the standard basis at 0, we have $e(\epsilon) \perp e_0$ for all $\epsilon$. We also note that $e(\epsilon)$ is a unit vector for all $\epsilon$.

Now, we define,

$$x(\epsilon, q) = \begin{cases}
\frac{1}{2}e_0&, \text{ if }\epsilon > q\\
\frac{1}{2}e_0 + \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{q - \epsilon}{q/2}e(\epsilon)&, \text{ if }\frac{q}{2} < \epsilon \leq q\\
(1 - \frac{\epsilon}{q})e_0 + \sqrt{(1 - \frac{\epsilon}{q})\frac{\epsilon}{q}}e(\epsilon)&, \text{ if }\epsilon \leq \frac{q}{2}
\end{cases}$$

I’ll leave it to you to check that this is indeed continuous on $(0, 1] \times [0, 1]$. Furthermore, you can calculate that,

$$x^\ast(q) = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} x(\epsilon, q) = \begin{cases}
\frac{1}{2}e_0&, \text{ if }q = 0\\
e_0&, \text{ otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

When $q = 0$, $\langle x^\ast(q) - x(\epsilon, q), x(\epsilon, q)\rangle = 0$ for all $\epsilon$. If $q > 0$, we verify the three cases in the definition of $x(\epsilon, q)$ one-by-one: if $\epsilon > q$, then,

$$\langle x^\ast(q) - x(\epsilon, q), x(\epsilon, q)\rangle = \langle \frac{1}{2}e_0, \frac{1}{2}e_0\rangle = \frac{1}{4}$$

If $\frac{q}{2} < \epsilon \leq q$,

$$\langle x^\ast(q) - x(\epsilon, q), x(\epsilon, q)\rangle = \langle \frac{1}{2}e_0 - \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{q - \epsilon}{q/2}e(\epsilon), \frac{1}{2}e_0 + \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{q - \epsilon}{q/2}e(\epsilon)\rangle$$

Since $e(\epsilon)$ is a unit vector orthogonal to $e_0$ and $0 \leq \frac{q - \epsilon}{q/2} < 1$, we have,

$$\langle \frac{1}{2}e_0 - \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{q - \epsilon}{q/2}e(\epsilon), \frac{1}{2}e_0 + \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{q - \epsilon}{q/2}e(\epsilon)\rangle = \frac{1}{4} - \frac{1}{4} \cdot (\frac{q - \epsilon}{q/2})^2 \geq 0$$

That is, $\langle x^\ast(q) - x(\epsilon, q), x(\epsilon, q)\rangle \geq 0$. Finally, if $\epsilon \leq \frac{q}{2}$, then, again as $e(\epsilon)$ is a unit vector orthogonal to $e_0$,

$$\langle x^\ast(q) - x(\epsilon, q), x(\epsilon, q)\rangle = \langle \frac{\epsilon}{q}e_0 - \sqrt{(1 - \frac{\epsilon}{q})\frac{\epsilon}{q}}e(\epsilon), (1 - \frac{\epsilon}{q})e_0 + \sqrt{(1 - \frac{\epsilon}{q})\frac{\epsilon}{q}}e(\epsilon)\rangle = (1 - \frac{\epsilon}{q})\frac{\epsilon}{q} - (1 - \frac{\epsilon}{q})\frac{\epsilon}{q} = 0$$

This verifies that the example satisfies the additional assumption. However, $X = \text{range}(x)$ is still not relatively compact. Indeed, for any $n \geq 1$, $X \ni x(\frac{1}{2n}, \frac{1}{n}) = \frac{1}{2}e_0 + \frac{1}{2}e(\frac{1}{2n}) = \frac{1}{2}e_0 + \frac{1}{2}e_{2n}$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In the context I am looking at the problem the function $x$ has an additional property: 

  $\forall q \in \mathcal{Q}$ it holds that $\langle x^*(q) - x(\varepsilon, q), x(\varepsilon, q) \rangle \ge 0$ for all $\varepsilon \in (0,1]$. 

Do you think this property can help to show compactness?

Comment: @AverageJoe My intuition is that this additional property won’t help, but any counterexample will certainly have to be more elaborate than the one in this answer. I’ll think about this.

Comment: @AverageJoe I’ve added a new counterexample showing that this additional assumption is still not enough to guarantee relative compactness.

Comment: @AverageJoe I should point out that in this example, $x^\ast(q)$ is not continuous in $q$ - you can show that if you impose both your additional assumption *and* the assumption that $x^\ast(q)$ is continuous, then you do have relative compactness.